# Insert values in a column depending upon cell values Sql

Tags: sql

I have a table in SQL database (see below)

```
Customer ID Nationality
------------------------
10001   
10002   
10003   
10004   
10005
```

and I have a spreadsheet

[image]

```
Customer ID Nationality
------------------------
10001       Russian
10002       Swiss
10003       Italian
10004       French
10005       Swiss
```

I am trying to write a code that can update /insert values in database so that the database table looks same as spreadsheet.

Comment: Have you tried `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: do not upload images if you can

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.)?  Also, have you already loaded your spreadsheet into SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below update script-

```
UPDATE your_table
SET Nationality = 
CASE
    WHEN Customer_ID =  10001 THEN 'Russian'
    WHEN Customer_ID =  10002 THEN 'Swiss'
    WHEN Customer_ID =  10003 THEN 'Italian'
    WHEN Customer_ID =  10004 THEN 'French'
    WHEN Customer_ID =  10004 THEN 'Swiss'
    ELSE 'Other'
END
WHERE Nationality IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting an error "Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Nationality ', table 'your_table'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: @Anoop, please check I have added the ELSE condition. You can use any text in place of other. This should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you mkRabbani! Sorry that I didnt explain my question correctly..apologies..my database has existing data in the column Nationality some are empty as well. I only want to update the values mention in query and no changes to other values.

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't it update All empty cells? I dont want to change any existing field (even if its blank). Just want to alter the cells which will be mentioned in script. For example I only want to update the 5 values mentioned in spreadsheet and no change to orhers.

Comment: @Anoop, You can separate your targeted rows easily. For example - "WHERE Nationality IS NULL AND Customer_ID IN (10001,10002,10003,10004,10004)". You can use the filtering condition for any required column.

Comment: Dear mkRabbani, I have accepted your answer and voted.

Comment: Thanks @Anoop :)